# echo server is not signing Helm chart

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, gnupg

I am attempting to create a microservice (echo server in go) that I can deploy in a Kubernetes environment that will simply sign a Helm chart. The idea is that I will mount a keyring (using Vault) to the pod(s) running the service, and then our CI system can POST a chart.tgz to an endpoint, which will sign the chart (generate a .prov file) and then upload this provenance file to our registry.

All configuration information is provided using a yaml file and marshaled to a struct with viper. I am using the official helm go pkg for [provenance](https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3@v3.13.2/pkg/provenance)

**Expected behavior**
The provided chart is signed using a key from a GPG keyring, which can then be uploaded to our registry (in this case Nexus).

**Actual Behavior**
No .prov file is created, and when one is it is 0 bytes.

This is where the issue is occurring in the [server](https://github.com/mkm29/helmpilot/blob/main/pkg/server/server.go#L212-L214) pkg, and if you run this you will see that the signature is always being returned as an empty string (not an error). [source](https://github.com/mkm29/helmpilot/blob/main/pkg/helm/package.go#L68)

Thanks!